# Token creation misstep

Tags: nft

I created my token and it appeared on Birds Eye, then I created the market book and added the liquidity pool and then what showed up on dex scanner isn’t the same profile on Birds Eye that has a much higher market cap but shows no liquidity. My token is live and trading but I’ve also found that someone can purchase most of the available tokens for not a lot of money. How is my market cap supposed to go up? iOS it just by having more holders or did I create a pool for the wrong contract? I’m in the weeds